# failed install npm version 3.10.9

Tags: npm, npm-install

i run `npm i -g npm@3.10.9`
and then it says

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fs-write-stream-atomic/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/move-concurrently/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/herdyan/.npm/_logs/2020-07-09T03_08_01_073Z-debug.log
```

is it because i already have  npm@6.14.6 when i check it with npm list -g --depth=0

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`?

Comment: im sorry, did you mean sudo npm i  -g npm@3.10.9?

Comment: yes it's done sir thankyou very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since im new in this npm-install, i still dont know how to solve it, thanks to @Mateen so i decided to put `sudo` in `sudo npm i -g npm@3.10.9`

Comment: Welcome, FYI it's actually about Permission of your system, how you give access to.

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed NodeJS as root or using sudo. When this happens, you need to have super user permissions to install/update npm and anything else.

The ideal situation is installing NodeJS in user space, preferably using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), which allows you to have many different version of NodeJS installed and easily change from one to another.